# Handle unhandled exceptions only from certain assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

Well, maybe a odd question, but how would I handle unhandled exceptions only from certain assemblies in a application, but including exceptions that originate from .NET itself, like for instance when you get a ADO.NET exception it originates from .NET assembly.

I need this because of working with the legacy application where I need unhandled exception handling only for a module consisting of several assemblies, and everything is in the same application in the end, as a part of same process.

Can I maybe catch exceptions on assembly level, instead on the global Application level ?

Comment: Dennis, just out of curiosity: was any of the answers below helpful to you are are you still waiting for the silver bullet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the stack trace and use `throw;` if you should not handle the exception.

```
try
{
    //something
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    if (!err.StackTrace.Contains("YourAssemblyName"))
        throw;
}
```

Comment: yeah, I thought of this as well, but stacktrace contains folder names as well, and what if some folder is named same as the assembly

Comment: Include a space like `" YourAssemblyName"`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you please explain how would the space help in this case ?

Comment: Because a folder wont start with a space and all stack trace items start with " at assembly.namespace", but the "at" may change for different OS languages

Answer (score 1):

No but you can catch at AppDomain level. If the modification is relevant in your application try to :

- Create a new [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.createdomain%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
- [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.load%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) or [execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.executeassembly%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) the relevant assemblies in it.
- [Catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) the unhandled exceptions of the domain

EDIT :

```
        AppDomain otherAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("myDomain");
        otherAppDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(otherAppDomain_UnhandledException);
        Assembly assembly = otherAppDomain.Load("TheAssemblyThatThrows");
        // But you might need to have MyClass inherit from MarshalByRefObject
        MyClass instance = (MyClass)otherAppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("TheAssemblyThatThrows", "MyClass");
        instance.DoSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course I don't know the number of calls to the assemblies you want to isolate, so I don't know if this is feasible, but to me it seems that creating a facade around the module you're talking about would be appropriate.

The facade would catch the exceptions that are thrown from these specific assemblies and could rethrow a custom exception with the original exception as `InnerException`. The custom exception is easily recognized by the global exception handler.

Answer (score -1):

you could write one from scratch, but http://code.google.com/p/elmah/ is a great framework for handling unhandled exceptions!

you could then use http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering to filter per assembly using reflection.